# Meyers Singleton thread safe with C++-98

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, singleton, c++98

Currently I have this implementation of the meyer singleton:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    static ClassA& GetInstance()
    {                   
        static ClassA instance;     
        return instance;
    }   

private:
    ClassA::ClassA() {};

    // avoid copying singleton
    ClassA(ClassA const&);
    void operator = (ClassA const&);
};
```

Now I need some improvements to getting this code thread safe in C++-98 and VS-2008?!

Thanks!

PS: What is unclear? You see the tags visual-studio-2008 and c++-98 -> so the target OS is Windows! I also don't understand why I got down voted solely some people don't like Singleton's at all!

Comment: The simplest improvement is not to use a singleton.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know what synchronization mechanisms to use? As there are no threads in standard c++98, that depends - on the OS and the threading library you are using.

Comment: -1 for using a singleton at all, and vtc because you 1) haven't asked an actual *questions*, and 2) seem to think that stack overflow is a magic code generation machine.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Without knowing what he's using it for, you can't say that.  There are specific things for which the singleton is an appropriate solution.

Comment: @JohnDibling The question is obvious (and has a simple answer), and he may be perfectly justified using a singleton, since there are cases where the singleton is the best solution.  (Avoiding singletons on principle can be classified as an anti-pattern.)

Comment: I don't usually vote, but I'm giving this question an up-vote, because it is a good question, unjustifiably voted down.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I can, and will, say that there's never an appropriate use for singletons (although of course you're free to disagree); doubly so if you're trying to retrofit thread safety to C++98. To my knowledge, there's no way to implement a thread-safe singleton without the C++11 guarantees about local static objects.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You can, I suppose, say anything, but appropriate uses have been pointed out more than once, and no one has yet to present any argument that holds water against them in general.  (There are good reasons not to use them too often, of course.  But then, you can say the same thing about just about any advanced language feature as well.)

Comment: What is unclear? You see the tags visual-studio-2008 and c++-98 -> so the target OS is Windows! I also don't understand why I got down voted solely some people don't like Singleton's at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Meyer singleton isn't the best solution in general, and
especially not in a multithreaded environment.  A more general
way of implementing a singleton would be:

```
class ClassA
{
    static ClassA* ourInstance;
    //  ctor's, etc.
public:
    static ClassA& instance();
};
```

and in the source file:

```
ClassA* ClassA::ourInstance = &instance();

// This can be in any source file.
ClassA&
ClassA::instance()
{
    if ( ourInstance == NULL ) {
        ourInstance = new ClassA;
    }
    return *ourInstance;
}
```

This is thread safe *if* no threads are created before entering
`main` (which should be the case), and it is not dynamically
loaded (which should also be the case—if the object is to
be unique, and accessible from the constructors of static
objects, then it has to be their when the static constructors
run).  It also has the advantage of avoiding any order of
destruction problems.

Comment: Doesn't your reasoning that this is thread-safe work for the original code?

Comment: Is the static member guaranteed to be initialised before entering `main`, even if it's in a different translation unit? It's specifically not guaranteed in C++11, but C++98/03 seems to me to be rather more vague.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Officially, I don't think it's guaranteed even in C++11.  Practically, there's so much code that depends on it that I don't think you have to worry.

Comment: @GManNickG No.  The original code didn't have any guarantee that `ClassA::instance` would be called before entering `main`.  My code does.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's specifically *not* guaranteed in C++11; 3.6.2/4 says "It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main." The corresponding sentence in C++98 only refers to "objects at namespace scope", but as far as I can see never says anything about any other kind of static variable. You may not worry about relying on implementation-defined or unspecified behaviour, but I certainly do.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Which is more or less what I thought.  Why it's not guaranteed, I don't know; all implementations effectively do do static initialization before entering main.  Historically, it's more or less in the same category as a non-contiguous representation of a string---there was originally a desire to leave implementations additional freedom, but it turns out that there's nothing interesting they can do with that freedom.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's to allow late loading of dynamic libraries. This happens on Linux; your attempt at thread safety will fail on that platform if the singleton is in a shared library. (I know very little about Windows, so can't comment on whether this is a valid but non-portable solution for this particular question)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Once you use dynamic loading, you're in undefined behavior as far as the C++ standard is concerned.  And yes, the singleton has to be in the same unit which contains main; it doesn't work if its in a shared library.  But the sort of things for which singletons are appropriate generally don't belong in shared libraries anyway.  If there really can and should be only one of something, it probably should be there before you load any shared library.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Then the answer should contain these caveats; as it is, it's dangerously misleading, implying that this kind of initialisation is generally thread-safe. And dynamic loading (by the implementation, of complete translation units) certainly isn't "undefined behaviour"; the standard is quite clear about what you can and can't rely on (apart from the vagueness I mentioned in C++98, fixed in C++11).

Comment: @leon22 What first method?  The only function in the code I present is `ClassA::instance`, and it does what it is supposed to do: if the pointer is null, it creates a new instance and initializes the pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze It was another error (it comes not from your code)! Thx anyway!