# Thread safe singleton implementation : whats wrong?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, singleton

This question was closed as duplicate and hence making the question more explicit and reopening the question:

The questions are :

1) Is the implementation below thread safe or not?

2) What are the problems with the below approach (except for complexity)

```
class Singleton
{
    public:
    static void init (){
        static Singleton _single ;
        cout<<"Called"<<endl;
        m_Singleton = &_single ;
    }
    static Singleton & instance ()
    {
        static pthread_once_t once_flag = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
        cout<<(unsigned int)PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT<<endl;
        pthread_once(&once_flag, &Singleton::init) ;
        return *m_Singleton;
    }
    static Singleton* m_Singleton;
    private:
    Singleton (){}
    Singleton (const Singleton&) ;
    Singleton operator=(Singleton&) ;
};
```

I'm counting on that something's wrong with this implementation hence not suggested anywhere

Thanks

Comment: better yet, don't use singletons

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: you search for design patterns and you find singleton is the most widely discussed. I may not use it but sure wanted to understand what are the challenges and problems underneath.

Comment: Just curious, why there are votes to close the question?

Comment: @FredOverflow: I checked the provided link but Meyer's impl is not thread safe (before C++11). As well couple of links provided in the accepted answer are broken. The question shall be marked duplicate if I post Meyer's implementation and ask if it is thread safe. My question is if the implementation is question is thread safe or not and what are the problems with it.

Comment: It's threadsafe, but not exception-safe. It has undefined behavior if the Singleton constructor throws an exception.

Comment: @Casey: is it because the exception will be trapped within thread library function? How about a NULL check after pthread_once?

Comment: @hype The exception will certainly propagate out of `pthread_once`, and `m_Singleton` will still be `nullptr`. The problem is that it's not clear what the state of `once_flag` will be, or what will happen to other threads waiting on the thread that was performing the initialization. For example, if `pthread_once` really is a C function implemented with a `pthread_mutex`, it's possible that the exception will bypass unlocking that mutex and the waiting threads will wait forever. You'd avoid all that using `std::call_once` with a `std::once_flag` from the C++11 standard library.

Comment: @Casey: Thanks, makes sense. Exactly for these reasons I see the question was not duplicate.

Comment: I agree that this specific instance is not covered by the"duplicate" question, one of those reopen votes is mine.

Answer (score 1):

> what's wrong?

It is too complicated. Just use this (assuming you really want a singleton):

```
static Singleton & instance ()
    static Singleton _single;
    cout<<"Called"<<endl;
    return _single ;
}
```

Comment: Is it thread safe (before C++11)?

Comment: @hype No, it is not, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924688/meyers-singleton-thread-safe-with-c-98).

Comment: Yes..so I come back to my question :) Is the implementation in question thread safe and except that it is complicated (already agreed), are there any other problems with it?

Comment: @hype On the surface it looks OK, but my `pthreads` knowledge is rusty (I've been using `Boost.Thread` and C++11 threading lib for too long.